# "The funnier the post, the tireder I get"

Tags: comparative

> “The ***funnier*** the post, the ***tireder*** I get."

Can that sentence, which has been written by a native speaker, be good English?

I ask in reference to how 'funnier' and 'tireder' are used, obviously.

Comment: It's perfectly fine. A funny post makes me tired; a funnier post makes tireder. (And, Yes, *tireder* is fine; in many dialects *tired* is not merely notionally but actually monosyllabic.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "good English".  On the one hand, I'm sure it's what they meant to write, and anyone can understand it.  So in that sense, it contains zero mistakes.  Informally speaking, I think it's perfectly acceptable.

On the other hand, it's definitely non-standard English.  It's not the sort of thing you'd want to write in formal or even semi-formal contexts, where this sort of wordplay is inappropriate.  If you were trying to write standard English, using the word **tireder* would indeed be a mistake.  *More tired* is the normal way to write it; in [COCA](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/), I find 173 results for *more tired*, but only 3 for *tireder*.

Why?  *Tired* belongs to a subclass of adjectives called *participial adjectives*, derived from the *-ing* and *-ed* forms of verbs.  Although people do add the comparative *-er* and superlative *-est* to participial adjectives, it's usually considered nonstandard to do so.  Instead, they standardly appear in periphrastic constructions with *more* and *most*:

> *more bored*, not **boreder*
>   *more interesting*, not **interestinger*
>   *more overwhelming*, not **overwhelminger*
>   *more shocked*, not **shockeder*
>   *more surprising*, not **surprisinger*
>   *more thrilled*, not **thrilleder*
>   *more tired*, not **tireder*

As you can see, this rule applies even if the participial adjective is monosyllablic, as in *bored*.

*Funnier*, on the other hand, is perfectly standard.  It's much more common than the alternative *more funny*; in COCA, I find 475 results for *funnier* and only 27 for *more funny*.

Comment: snail, thank you, +1, but why don't you expand the answer to explain why 'tireder' is uncommon, whereas 'funnier' is largely used?

Comment: @user2793 I expanded the answer somewhat.

Comment: When my dad would make a blunder because he was rushing through something, he'd utter one of his favorite maxims: _"The hurrieder I go, the behinder I get."_ Of course, a better (i.e., more formal) English wording would be "The more I rush the job, the longer it takes to finish." That may get rid of those red squiggly lines that my spell-checker is putting beneath my dad's version, but a lot of the simple charm in his version would be lost in the edit.